# How to get Jar file - Lift-JSON for Scala 2.10.1?

Tags: json, scala, lift-json

I tried and completed these steps,

Downloaded Lift2.5 Version 
and changed scala_210/lift_json/build.sbt  file with my scala version

After that I ran build.sbt file.
After some downloads and some updating all showing Successfully Done.

After I got these lines on terminal

```
[info] Updating {file:/home/srujan/Downloads/lift-lift_25_sbt-b67dc62/scala_210/lift_json/}default-3b2806...
[info] Resolving org.specs2#scalaz-core_2.10;7.0.0 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Successfully created Eclipse project files for project(s):
[info] Lift 2.5 starter template
> eclipse
[info] About to create Eclipse project files for your project(s).
[info] Successfully created Eclipse project files for project(s):
[info] Lift 2.5 starter template
>
```

What should I do after this step?

Please help me

Comment: SBT uses ivy to perform dependency resolution. Checkout `~/.ivy2/cache` directories if you badly need jar file.

Comment: println(compact(render(json))) i am getting error on Compact